# angularjs filter to return only the exact matching values

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a checkbox as a filter in my angularjs app :

this is my data :

```
app.controller('listdata', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.users = [{
    "name": "pravin",
    "queue": [{
        "number": "456",
        "status": "Unavailable"
    }],
    "phone": "7411173737"
},
{
    "name": "pratik",
    "queue": [{
        "number": "111",
        "status": "Unavailable"
    }],
    "phone": "8558855858"
},
{
    "name": "priyanka",
    "queue": [{
        "number": "111",
        "status": "Unavailable"
    }],
    "phone": "5454573737"
},
{
    "name": "prerana",
    "queue": [{
        "number": "111",
        "status": "Unavailable"
    }],
    "phone": "7454543737"
}];

});
```

I'm displaying the above data in my view like this :

//this is the filter

```
<label class="switch">
  <input ng-true-value='111' ng-false-value='' type="checkbox" ng-model="queue111">111
</label>
```

//ng-repeat part

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="listdata">
    <div ng-repeat="user in users|filter:queue111">
       <p> {{user.name}} {{user.phone}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I start the app all the four users from the users data array are displayed.
When I click on the filter checkbox, it displays the users who have a queue with a number 111. but it also displays the user pravin as it contains a phone number 7411173737 which contains 111. I want this filter to only display records whose queue number matches with 111 and not with any other fields like the phone number here. So the filter should only display records where the queue number is 111.

is it possible to do something like

`<input ng-true-value='111' ng-false-value='' type="checkbox" ng-model="queue111.queue.number">111`

> Current output : it displays all the four data objects in $scope.users
>
> Expected output : display only the data objects where in queue number
>   is 111 in $scope.users

how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this custom filter function to match only values inside the queue array.

```js
var Controller = function($scope) {
  $scope.users = [{
      "name": "pravin",
      "queue": [{
        "number": "456",
        "status": "Unavailable"
      }],
      "phone": "7411173737"
    },
    {
      "name": "pratik",
      "queue": [{
        "number": "111",
        "status": "Unavailable"
      }],
      "phone": "8558855858"
    },
    {
      "name": "priyanka",
      "queue": [{
        "number": "111",
        "status": "Unavailable"
      }],
      "phone": "5454573737"
    },
    {
      "name": "prerana",
      "queue": [{
        "number": "111",
        "status": "Unavailable"
      }],
      "phone": "7454543737"
    }
  ];

  $scope.filter = function(item) {
    if ($scope.queue111) {
      return JSON.stringify(item.queue).includes($scope.queue111);
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  };

};

angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('Controller', Controller);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller">
  <label class="switch">
    <input ng-true-value='111' ng-false-value='' type="checkbox" ng-model="queue111">
  </label>
  <pre>Search value: {{queue111}}</pre>
  <div ng-repeat="user in users | filter:filter">
    {{user.name}} {{user.phone}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your answer looks promising. I will try it and will let you know :)

Comment: hey how to do it when I'm using $scope? I really can't use vm as I'll have to modify a lot of existing code and my code is already very lengthy

Comment: please see my updated question for the controller structure

Comment: for some reason I can't do it like var Controller = function() as per your answer. I have to do it as per my existing code structure. please help

Comment: I got it. please see my answer

Comment: Code updated, my aswer looks cleaner, glad It helped you taking this forward

Comment: can you help me with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53700568/angularjs-custom-filter-to-check-for-values-inside-a-data-array)

Comment: Just did! let me know If it helps! =)

Comment: yea it helped a lot. upvoted and accepted. thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it like this by using a custom function and the ternary operator in the filter:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('listdata', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.users = [{
    "name": "pravin",
    "queue": [{
        "number": "456",
        "status": "Unavailable"
    }],
    "phone": "7411173737"
},
{
    "name": "pratik",
    "queue": [{
        "number": "111",
        "status": "Unavailable"
    },
    {
        "number": "112",
        "status": "Unavailable"
    }],
    "phone": "8558855858"
},
{
    "name": "priyanka",
    "queue": [{
        "number": "111",
        "status": "Unavailable"
    }],
    "phone": "5454573737"
},
{
    "name": "prerana",
    "queue": [{
        "number": "111",
        "status": "Unavailable"
    }],
    "phone": "7454543737"
}];
   $scope.filter111 = function (user) {
            return (user.queue.find(({number}) => number === '111'));
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="queue111">111
</label>


<div class="row" ng-controller="listdata">

  <div ng-repeat="user in users|filter: queue111? filter111: ''">
    <p> {{user.name}} {{user.phone}}</p>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just pass true to the filter to enable strict matching.

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users|filter:queue111:true">
```

Comment: Strict matching will search in all the object, I think he is trying to match the queue array